# No Q bar on flip-flop

Tags: fpga, flipflop

I'm currently using Quartus and I'm trying to make a 4 bit counter. I noticed that when I imported the built-in flip-flop that there is no Q bar output. It's the same issue with the JK flip-flop as well. I'm trying to make an asynchronous up counter

I need the Q Bar output as this will be connected to the 'D' input. I was thinking about adding the inverter on the Q output but I can't, as I'm making an up counter.

Thanks to all in advance.

[image: what im trying to make][image: D flipflop]

Comment: The question makes no sense. Why would anything prevent you from creating "Q-bar" using an inverter? You can still use "Q"...

Comment: Q is meant to be the output and the Q' was meant to connect to the clock aswell as the 'D' input

Comment: @Neamus But that's not an answer. Q-bar is the inverse of Q. By definition, that's what it is - that's what the bar means. So if you don't have a Q-bar provided, invert Q and you have a Q-bar signal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FFs on FPGAs don't have explicit "Q-bar" outputs, because inverters are basically available "for free" as a result of how logic is implemented in LUTs (lookup tables).

You can just add the inverter, and it will be incorporated into every LUT that it feeds.

In any case, a ripple counter like the one you have shown is a poor choice for FPGA implementation. It is far better to use a synchronous counter.

Comment: I would be rather surprised if Quartus will let you build a ripple counter without bitching, most FPGA tools do not like mixing clock and data because it makes timing closure hard. If you just write a register with a input <= output + 1 wrapped around it the tool will probably use one of the built in carry chains to build your counter for you (and it will be properly synchronous).

Comment: Oooh, “Q-bar” means “Q'” i.e. the inverse, “NOT Q”?. Never heard that term before.

Comment: @DanMills Depends on the FPGA, I guess, there are a few Intel FPGA's that have surprisingly finely meshed clock nets and these might be able to do it. But in general, yeah, there's no reason for this bit fiddling anymore. Most of these questions either complete beginner hobby projects or some inane uni task.

Comment: The clock enable, set, and reset inputs on FDRSE primitives in 7-Series Xilinx FPGAs must be active high.  So having access to NOT-Q would be beneficial if you want to set, reset, or clock-enable FFs when a register is low.  Because without it one would have to use an extra LUT to invert the signal for the enable.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an inverter, and then you'll add some combinatorial logic on each D input to get a synchronous up counter. Or you could make a ring counter.